# Java persistence - No parrent key found after flushing

Tags: java, jpa, persistence

I have two entity object that represent two database table.

There is a foreign key relationship beetween two fields in the tables..

I am try to create a new instance from one entity and persist, then try to create another and pass the first object to the secound object as paramter in the set...() method.

But it throws Constraint violation exception because parent key not found in the database then the transaction rolled back.

```
BPackage newCond = new BPackage();
        newCond.setName(condomName);
              //...
               //...
try {
            em.persist(newCond);
            em.flush();
        } catch (ConstraintViolationException e) {
            LOG.warning(e.getMessage());
            return null;
        }
BAssocPackage newRel = new BAssocPackage();
        newRel.setPackageId(newCond); //here try to pass..
                 //... 
                  //...
try {
            em.persist(newRel);

        } catch (ConstraintViolationException e) {
            LOG.warning(e.getMessage());
            return null;
        }
```

My EntityManager is container managed so I can't close it.

```
 @Stateless
public class MainDataAccess implements MainDataAccessLocal {

    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "WarmHomeColl-ejbPU")
    private EntityManager em;
```

There is lot of properties in my entity classes, so i will not post all of them but this is my first entity:

```
public class BPackage implements Serializable {
//...
  //...
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "packageId")
    private Collection<BAssocPackage> bAssocPackageCollection;
//...
 //..

public class BAssocPackage implements Serializable {
//...
  //...
@JoinColumn(name = "PACKAGE_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID")
    @ManyToOne
    private BPackage packageId;
//...
 //..
```

Please help me. :) Thank you!

Comment: You should post the entities too. Not the entire thing, just the properties withh the JPA mapping annotations on them.

Comment: I posted the relevant part

Comment: You don't think that posting the key definitions is relevant when the problem is possibly related to key generation?

Comment: I don't know what should i post. Could you please describe me what key do you mean? Should I post how do I create the primary key of my entities or what?

Answer (score 0):

Solved it.

There was a trigger on the id field in the database and i wasn't refereed to a right id.. when i deleted the trigger from the field it start working fine..